# Check multiple condition inside onClick in android

Tags: android, mobile

i want to check multiple condition inside onClick method, but my code is not checking both condition

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    item = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if(v == convert && item == "Decimal"){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Decimal",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

when i remove

```
 && item == "Decimal"
```

it works fine

i am newbie to android, sorry for any silly question..

Comment: `if(item.equals("Decimal"))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Thanks all " if(item.equals("Decimal")) ". works for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this to check String equality .. it will work for you

```
item.equals("Decimal")
```